# Merge/synonymize [arquillian] and [jboss-arquillian]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

I noticed that these tags: [arquillian](/questions/tagged/arquillian) and [jboss-arquillian](/questions/tagged/jboss-arquillian) are almost identical. In fact [jboss-arquillian](/questions/tagged/jboss-arquillian) looks like a superset of [arquillian](/questions/tagged/arquillian) since most of the questions I checked in [arquillian](/questions/tagged/arquillian) have the other tag too.
The description of these tags is almost identical too:
[jboss-arquillian](/questions/tagged/jboss-arquillian):
JBoss Arquillian is a testing platform for the JVM that enables developers to create automated integration, functional and acceptance tests for Java middleware.

[arquillian](/questions/tagged/arquillian):
Arquillian is an extensible testing platform for the JVM that enables developers to easily create automated integration, functional and acceptance tests for Java middleware.

Comment: +1 I was about to report this, but don't have enough tag rep. They are the same project.